# Explain batch command please?

Tags: batch-file

Can someone explain what these batch commands do?

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%A in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Environment" /v timestamp ^|FIND "timestamp"') DO set timer=%%B
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `"tokens=2*"` part will take the text it's passed and split it into "tokens" (by default, space-separated words). It will then take all the words, starting with the second, and pass them in turn to variables with names starting with `%%A`; `%%A` will get word 2, and `%%B` will get the rest (word "*", if you like). See [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php) for more details.

The `REG QUERY ... /v` part looks up values in the registry. Since [this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntregquery.php) has plenty of information about how to use it, I won't go into more extensive detail.

The `FIND` command just searches for a text string in the output of the `REQ QUERY` part, using pipes to redirect the output of `REQ QUERY` to the input of `FIND`. See [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) for more detail about pipes.

The net result of this line in a batch file is to search the registry for any timestamp values under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`, and assign them to the batch variable `timer`.